# Google Analytics Custom Variable is not tracking Email Address

Tags: google-analytics, email-address

I am trying to track logged in customer's email address through google analytics custom variable. But, it's not being tracked by google analytics.

For testing purpose, I created another custom variable to track page title and it is working fine.

Here is my code:-

**Tracking Email** (Not Working)

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
        1, // Slot Number
        'Email', 
        'test@example.com', // Sample Email Address
        3 // Page Level Scope
    ]);
```

**Tracking Page Title** (Working)

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
        2, // Slot Number
        'Page', 
        'Homepage', // Sample Page Title
        3 // Page Level Scope
    ]);
```

Doesn't Google Analytics Track Emails?

Comment: Yes, GA can track emails or any other string through Custom Variables. Are these two code samples in the same area of your webpage? Also, they take a while to show up sometimes, have you given it a couple days?

Comment: Yes. They are on same area of the page. And, I am trying to track this since 1 week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't send any Personally identifiable information to Google Analytics.

From the [TOS](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html):

> 7 . PRIVACY . You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service to track or collect personally identifiable information of
>   Internet users, nor will You (or will You allow any third party to)
>   associate any data gathered from Your website(s) (or such third
>   parties' website(s)) with any personally identifying information from
>   any source as part of Your use (or such third parties' use) of the
>   Service. You will have and abide by an appropriate privacy policy and
>   will comply with all applicable laws relating to the collection of
>   information from visitors to Your websites. You must post a privacy
>   policy and that policy must provide notice of your use of a cookie
>   that collects anonymous traffic data.

Comment: I agree that its against the TOS, but nowhere in the documentation does it say you cannot track a potentially arbitrary email address.  How would Google know that the user visiting the site owns the email address stuck in the custom var?

Comment: Google could easily be using a mask to identify PII like emails before they enter the system